# Not reading my .txt file with passwords correctly in C

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio, file

For my code I need to make a .txt file containing a username (first name) and a password (last name). My code needs to read that file. If I entered the correct user name and password it will log me in. If it is incorrect it not log me in. So far in my name.txt file (the file containing my usernames and passwords) I have Lebron James, Joe Smith. As I run my code i just get "could not open file names.txt" to display in the command prompt. Any idea on what changes i need to make to my code?

```
//This is my code:
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#define MAX_USER 32 

void get_input(const char *pszPrompt, char *cpszWord, const size_t iLength)
{
while (1) {
    printf("%s> ", pszPrompt);
    if (fgets(cpszWord, iLength * sizeof(char), stdin)) {
        break;
    }
}
size_t iLen = strlen(cpszWord);
if (cpszWord[iLen - 1] == '\n')
    cpszWord[iLen - 1] = 0;
}

int compare(FILE *f, const char *szUser, const char *szPassword)
{
int iFound = 0;
char szName[MAX_USER], szPW[MAX_USER];
while (!feof(f) && iFound != 2) {
    iFound = 0;
    if (fscanf(f, "%s %s", szName, szPW) == 2) {
        if (!strcmp(szName, szUser)) {
            ++iFound;
        }
        if (!strcmp(szPassword, szPW)) {
            ++iFound;
        }
    }
}
return iFound;
}

int main()
{
const char szFile[] = "names.txt";
char user[MAX_USER], password[MAX_USER];
int iFound = 0;
do {
    FILE *f = fopen(szFile, "rt");
    if (!f) {
        printf("Could not open file %s\n", szFile);
        break;
    }
    get_input(" User", user, sizeof(user));
    get_input("Password", password, sizeof(password));
    iFound = compare(f, user, password);
    fclose(f);
    if (iFound == 1) {
        printf("Wrong Password!\n");
    }
} while (iFound && iFound < 2);
if (iFound == 2) {
    printf("Welcome User!\n");
}



system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `t` flag for `fopen` is not defined, so function fails and `errno` should be `EINVAL`.

Comment: If you can't open the file then either the file is in the wrong place or your working directory is incorrect.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès It's valid in Visual Studio.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: @RetiredNinja where should the file be located?

Comment: The working directory defaults to where the project is, so copy your file there or change the working directory.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499391/change-current-working-directory-vs13

Comment: anyone know where i should put the location of the file that it is reading?

Answer (score 0):

> anyone know where i should put the location of the file that it is reading?

If you mean where to specify a known path to your existing file, then just before the filename, e. g.:

```
const char szFile[] = "C:/Users/Public/Documents/names.txt";
```

If you mean where to put your file without having to specify a path, then you can find out with e. g.:

```
#include <direct.h>
…
    puts(_getcwd(NULL, 0));
```